# how i redirect the transaction to use my wallet rather than metamask on chrome?

Tags: web3js, bsc, defi

how I redirect the transaction to use my wallet rather than metamask on chrome ?
I have created a wallet and I want to use it in my next transactions, but I don't know the process of linking it with websites so I can have the transaction info(Adresse, qty..)

Answer (score 0):

Start here to learn all about it!

https://codewithchris.com/submit-your-app-to-the-app-store/

The process will be somewhat the same for the chrome store and windows

If you want to hit the market really hard you should aim for an IE wallet integration while your at it!